# How to get the predicted value of the same label based on test data using GNN?

Tags: gnn

This is my method, `model.predict_generator`. Whether the predicted data still generates corresponding output according to the labels of the original data set.There is corresponding data under each label, and some labels have missing data. How to explain it?